# Simple mysql join for specific date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables friends and birthdays.

birthdays schema: userid and birthday_date

friends schema: userid and userid2.

How can I find out the friends of the people who have a birthday day today?
I am thinking something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM friends
WHERE userid2 IN
    (SELECT userid
     FROM birthdays
     WHERE birthday_date='05/02')
```

Is this the best way to do it?

Here is the EXPLAIN response that I get:

```
+----+--------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------+-----------------------+---------+---------+------+-----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table                       | type            | possible_keys         | key     | key_len | ref  | rows      | Extra                    |
+----+--------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------+-----------------------+---------+---------+------+-----------+--------------------------+
| 1  | PRIMARY            | friends          | index           | NULL                  | userid2  | 8       | NULL | 4192662 | Using where; Using index |
| 2  | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | birthdays | unique_subquery | PRIMARY,birthday_date | PRIMARY | 8       | func | 1         | Using where              |
+----+--------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------+-----------------------+---------+---------+------+-----------+--------------------------+
```

It doesn't seem optimized if it is searching 4 million rows.

Also, there are indexes on every column.

Comment: Have you got any error?

Comment: how birthday_date is stored in the DB ?

Comment: userid is bigint. birthday_date is varchar

Comment: I have added explain result to question

Comment: A simple join often is much faster than a subqery, especially a `DEPENDENT SUBQUERY`. So the most important part in @AbhikChakraborty's answer is the `inner join`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TO make the query faster you need proper index on both tables in conjunction with the JOIN.

Here is an example

```
create table birthdays (userid int,birthday_date varchar(20));
insert into birthdays values (1,'1980-01-01');
insert into birthdays values(2,'1980-01-02');
insert into birthdays values(3,'1980-01-03');
insert into birthdays values(4,'1980-01-04');
insert into birthdays values(5,'1980-01-05');
insert into birthdays values(6,'1980-01-06');
insert into birthdays values(7,'1980-01-07');

create table friends(userid int, userid2 int);
insert into friends values(3,1);
insert into friends values(1,3);
insert into friends values(1,5);
insert into friends values(2,3);
insert into friends values (7,6);

alter table birthdays add index bday_idx (`birthday_date`);
alter table birthdays add index iduser_idx (`userid`);

alter table friends add index userid2_idx(userid2)
```

Now if I run the following query it will be for sure way faster

```
SELECT f.*
FROM friends f 
inner join birthdays b on b.userid = f.userid2 
WHERE b.birthday_date='1980-01-01'

ID  SELECT_TYPE     TABLE   TYPE    POSSIBLE_KEYS   KEY     KEY_LEN     REF     ROWS    EXTRA
1   SIMPLE  b   ref     bday_idx,iduser_idx     bday_idx    63  const   1   Using where
1   SIMPLE  f   ref     userid2_idx     userid2_idx     5   db_2_99839.b.userid     1   Using where
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/99839/2)**

> NOTE : When you join 2 tables with a common key make sure both of them
>   are of same datatype and length, in the above example its joining
>   userid (birthday) and userid2(friends) so they are of same data type
>   and length. Where condition column needs to be indexed for faster
>   fetch and the optimizer will take index into account.

Comment: Thank you for the excellent answer!! I have put indexes on all the columns. If I want to run WHERE birthday_date LIKE '05/02%', then it is significantly slower. Do you know if there is a way to speed that up?

Comment: no it should take index into account if you use `like 'const%'` check here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html B-Tree Index Characteristics  section

Comment: Think carefully about storing dates as pure Strings. If you use `DATE`-type instead, you get a lot of functions like `between start and end`, so you can avoid pure string functions.

Comment: yes and its always better to store use date column with date or datetime datatype and use range query or equal to, also using conversion function like DATE() etc on such query will not consider the index.

Comment: It is varchar because some birthdays are listed as 05/02 and some are listed as 05/02/1940. Mysql seems to require an year for datetime/date.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Query Example

```
SELECT friends.*
FROM friends inner join birthdays on friends.userid2 = birthdays.userid 
WHERE birthdays.birthday_date='05/02/2014'
```

Always use `datetime` datatype for date values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is varchar because some birthdays are listed as 05/02 and some are listed as 05/02/1940. Mysql seems to require an year for datetime.

Comment: If I want to run WHERE birthday_date LIKE '05/02%', then it is significantly slower. Do you know if there is a way to speed that up?

Comment: then you can use index for column. follow at dev,mysql.com for support

Answer (score 0):

On MySQL, JOINS perform much faster than nested SELECT statements. Therefore, to start with, I would write a SQL statement like this:

```
SELECT friends.* FROM friends
INNER JOIN birthdays ON (friends.userid2 = birthdays.userid)
WHERE birthdays.birthday_date >= [start date] AND birthdays.birthday_date <= [end date]
```

You can then replace [start date] and [end date] with todays date, or a range of dates, like this week, to return the appropriate records.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is significantly faster. Why are JOINS faster than nested SELECTs? Aren't they achieving the same end result in this case?

Comment: They have the same result, however it is the way that MySQL executes the statement that makes it faster. When using Oracle on the other hand, NESTED statements are faster than JOINS.